# What is the built-in kernel of CNN in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am studying CNN. I don't get the idea behind the kernels. How can we find them? I do some code in Tensorflow and I wonder what is the kernel in Tensorflow?

Comment: Please provide a code sample showing what you did and what you are trying to accomplish. CNNs learn filter kernels based on a maximum likelihood estimation.

Answer (score 2):

Any CNN does not use a predefined convolutional kernel, these are *learned* during the training process from the data. This is a common misconception with people that come from a signal processing background, where convolutional kernels are predefined (like edge detection, gabor filters, etc).